# Вывод по ключу в порядке убывания.

Tags: c++, хеширование

Есть простая хеш-функция key%m;
Массив из m=20 элементов
Есть 100 объектов, с рандомными ключами. 
Массив представляет собой массив стеков.

Задача:
Вывести элементы в порядке убывания ключа.

Проблема собственно в том, что самый максимальный ключ находится к примеру в 20 ячейке, следующий максимальный в 1, затем во второй, затем опять в 20-й.
Т.е. приходится вот так вот прыгать.

Собственно какие у меня варианты?

Собирать всё это в отдельный массив, сортировать его и потом выводить наверное не вариант.

Comment: А почему не вариант?

Comment: Ну, хотя на самом деле может быть и вариант. 
Просто может есть какие-то более "правильные" способы? 
К

Comment: Мне кажется, нету. Вам в любом случае надо будет в каком-то виде отсортировать. Если значения ключей произвольные, то нужна будет явная сортировка. Если ограничены какой-нибудь маленькой константой, то стоит воспользоваться [сортировкой подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_подсчётом). Вообще у вас же всего 100 элементов, сложно написать что-то медленно работающее.

Comment: Ну, тогда наверное так и поступлю. 
Спихну в массив, отсортирую по ключу и выведу. 
Спасибо.